# How to create several url targets in one link

Tags: html, href

I would like to create a link to several tabs in HTML. I know how to have one link that will open in another tab, but I'm not sure how to add an additional url that will open up simultaneously to the first one i a different tab as well.

```
<a href="url1" target="_blank">All the links in one button</a>
```

Comment: So you want to spam a user's browser with new tabs? You will have to use Javascript.

Comment: sorry it wasn't my intention to spam anyone. I just need to have a link that will open several tabs in one click instead of clicking each link separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do

```
<a href="url1" onclick="window.open('url2');" target="_blank">All
the links in one button</a>
```

That said, I think many browsers may block these kind of popups since they are used by spammers a lot.